# Spring Boot WebClient - Handle 200 as error in some cases based on the response body

Tags: spring, spring-webflux, webclient, project-reactor, reactive

I'm experimenting with Spring's WebClient and reactive framework, and I want to call a 3rd party API, that
handles errors in a really non-wanted way. There are cases, when for example the API Key does not exist, in this case
the API returns 401 which is easy to handle with a status handler function, but there are cases when the API key exists,
but it has no permission for specific resources.

In these cases the API returns an HTTP 200 OK BUT in the response body the **successful** field will be **false**, in other cases when
everything is okay, the permission, the it will be **true**. As Spring 6 just introduced the declarative way of creating
interfaces for clients, I thought lets give it a try, unfortunately I never used the Reactor framework nor the WebClient
directly, so it gives a bit of a hard time with the reactive nature.

My problem is that whenever I register a status handler function (Mono<? extends Throwable>) with the `defaultStatusHandler` method in the WebClient builder, and when I read the response body inside them, if I want to reuse it for the caller method, then it will always be null.

In technical terms, when I'm handling a 401 it is clear that I want to return an exception to the caller, because I want to break the flow
of the caller, but in case of HTTP 200 OK, I want to differentiate between to return the response body itself, or throw an exception if the
mentioned field (**successful**) is false.

Here is a [JBang](https://www.jbang.dev/) reproducer for the scenario with WireMock and the WebClient dependencies:

```java
///usr/bin/env jbang "$0" "$@" ; exit $?
//DEPS org.reflections:reflections:0.10.2
//DEPS org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:3.1.4@pom
//DEPS org.springframework.boot:spring-boot
//DEPS org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web
//DEPS org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux
//DEPS org.wiremock:wiremock:3.2.0
//JAVA 21

import com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.WireMockServer;
import com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.client.WireMock;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatusCode;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.ClientResponse;
import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClient;
import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.support.WebClientAdapter;
import org.springframework.web.service.annotation.PostExchange;
import org.springframework.web.service.invoker.HttpServiceProxyFactory;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;

import static org.springframework.http.MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE;

class WebClientErrorHandlerExample {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(WebClientErrorHandlerExample.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final WireMockServer wireMockServer = new WireMockServer(9999);
        wireMockServer.start();
        final var responseBuilder = WireMock.aResponse()
            .withStatus(200)
            .withHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
            .withBody("""
                          {
                           "successful":true,
                           "value":"Hello World"
                          }
                          """);
        wireMockServer.stubFor(WireMock.post(WireMock.urlPathMatching("/test")).willReturn(responseBuilder));

        final var client = setupClient();
        try {
            final ResponseEntity<ResponseClass> responseClassResponseEntity = client.callTest();
            System.out.println(responseClassResponseEntity.getBody());
        } catch (CustomException e) {
            LOGGER.error("CustomException:", e);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error("Exception:", e);
        }

        wireMockServer.shutdown();

    }

    private static TestHttpClient setupClient() {
        final var webClient = WebClient.builder()
            .baseUrl("http://localhost:9999")
            // With that the response body is returned, but I'm not able to handle the case
//            .defaultStatusHandler(HttpStatusCode::is2xxSuccessful, clientResponse -> emptyHandler(clientResponse))
            // With that the response body becomes null
//            .defaultStatusHandler(HttpStatusCode::is2xxSuccessful, WebClientErrorHandlerExample::handlerWithBodyRead)
            // With that the response body becomes null
//            .defaultStatusHandler(HttpStatusCode::is2xxSuccessful, WebClientErrorHandlerExample::withFilter)
            // With that the response body is returned, but I'm not able to handle the case
            .defaultStatusHandler(HttpStatusCode::is2xxSuccessful, WebClientErrorHandlerExample::handleWithHeaderRead)
            // With that as it blocks the framework will throw an exception
//            .defaultStatusHandler(HttpStatusCode::is2xxSuccessful, WebClientErrorHandlerExample::handleWithBlock)
            // With that the response body becomes null
//            .defaultStatusHandler(HttpStatusCode::is2xxSuccessful,WebClientErrorHandlerExample::handlerWithExceptionCreation)
            .build();
        final var clientAdapter = WebClientAdapter.forClient(webClient);
        return HttpServiceProxyFactory
            .builder(clientAdapter)
            .build()
            .createClient(TestHttpClient.class);
    }

    // Works, so it means it if it applied then the response body in the final place is returned correctly and not null
    private static Mono<? extends Throwable> emptyHandler(final ClientResponse clientResponse) {
        return Mono.empty();
    }

    // Works as it does not touch the response body
    private static Mono<? extends Throwable> handleWithHeaderRead(final ClientResponse clientResponse) {
        final var responseId = clientResponse.headers()
            .header("X-Response-Id");
        return Mono.empty();
    }

    // Does not work as it blocks
    private static Mono<? extends Throwable> handleWithBlock(final ClientResponse clientResponse) {
        final var response = clientResponse.bodyToMono(ResponseClass.class)
            .block();
        if(!response.successful) {
            return Mono.just(new CustomException("Error during call"));
        } else {
            return Mono.empty();
        }
    }

    // Does not work as it reads response body
    private static Mono<? extends Throwable> handlerWithBodyRead(final ClientResponse clientResponse) {
        return clientResponse.bodyToMono(ResponseClass.class)
            .flatMap(response -> {
                if (!response.successful) {
                    return Mono.just(new CustomException("Error during call"));
                } else {
                    return Mono.empty();
                }
            });
    }

    // Does not work as it reads response body
    private static Mono<? extends Throwable> withFilter(final ClientResponse clientResponse) {
        return clientResponse.bodyToMono(ResponseClass.class)
            .filter(response -> !response.successful)
            .flatMap(responseClass -> Mono.empty());
    }


    // Does not work as create error touches the response body
    private static Mono<? extends Throwable> handlerWithExceptionCreation(final ClientResponse clientResponse) {
        return clientResponse.createError()
            .flatMap(e -> Mono.empty());
    }

    interface TestHttpClient {

        @PostExchange(url = "/test", contentType = APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, accept = APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
        ResponseEntity<ResponseClass> callTest();

    }

    record ResponseClass(boolean successful, String value) {
    }

    static class CustomException extends RuntimeException {

        public CustomException(final String message) {
            super(message);
        }
    }
}
```

So my problem is that, as I'm just learning the Reactor framework and WebClient stuff, is that I'm just assuming that
after I read the response body within the handler function, it will become empty for later use OR the status handlers were not just
prepared for these scenarios which are so sad, as I have no power over the 3rd party framework.

When I checked the code that puts together the pipelines for the calls, I saw the following in the `DefaultResponseSpec` class (org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.DefaultWebClient.DefaultResponseSpec.handleBodyMono):

```java
class DefaultResponseSpec {

    private <T> Mono<T> handleBodyMono(ClientResponse response, Mono<T> body) {
        body = body.onErrorResume(WebClientUtils.WRAP_EXCEPTION_PREDICATE, exceptionWrappingFunction(response));
        Mono<T> result = applyStatusHandlers(response);
        return (result != null ? result.switchIfEmpty(body) : body);
    }

    private <T> Mono<T> applyStatusHandlers(ClientResponse response) {
        HttpStatusCode statusCode = response.statusCode();
        for (StatusHandler handler : this.statusHandlers) {
            if (handler.test(statusCode)) {
                Mono<? extends Throwable> exMono;
                try {
                    exMono = handler.apply(response);
                    exMono = exMono.flatMap(ex -> releaseIfNotConsumed(response, ex));
                    exMono = exMono.onErrorResume(ex -> releaseIfNotConsumed(response, ex));
                }
                catch (Throwable ex2) {
                    exMono = releaseIfNotConsumed(response, ex2);
                }
                Mono<T> result = exMono.flatMap(Mono::error);
                return result.checkpoint(statusCode + " from " +
                                             this.httpMethod + " " + getUriToLog(this.uri) + " [DefaultWebClient]");
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
    
}
```

From this, I thought if I return an empty Mono from the status handler function, than it will reuse the response body, but if I read it, that becomes null, which would make sense, but I just do not know if that is the case or I do something just wrong.

I did find a "workaround" so I can wrap my WebClient calls inside another class and I can handle the exceptional case,
but for the 401 I would register a status handler, and for the 200 I have to handle it "manually" or just let the other callers
do it for themselves, but it would be so bad for a module that will be used by multiple projects and multiple teams.

I hope somebody can give me some good tips advices on what I'm doing wrong.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't use block, call `map` instead and do your `if` inside the map function. I don't get why you are returning an empty mono, just return a mono with the body you just read, and don't use `Mono.just`, use `Mono.error` instead.

Comment: The handler code was intentionally put into the question.
I can not put the response body into the Mono as it should return a Mono that has a Throwable inside of it (`Mono<? extends Throwable>`).
On the other hand if I would use the `Mono.error` then the whole execution would end with an exception, and not the way I want it, the status handler function must return a Mono that should complete and should not end with an error case.
I thought if an empty Mono is returned, the handler code would re-use the response body, as it does if it is not read inside the handler.